# How to Install Linux distribution and run windows from it?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine

So I've recently decided on switching to Linux and running windows from within it (for day-to-day programs and games) and have Linux as a main OS for delicate stuff like bank details, etc...

Issue is I can't find anything explaining how this can be done, and since I'm a complete noob when it comes to Linux I've decided the best course of action would be to post here about it and see what you guys think and if anyone knows how to do this.

My current specs are: I7-6700k, 16Gb of DDR4 RAM, RTX2060, a main drive of 250GB and another of 1TB (both are m.2 NVME SSDs).

What I'm looking forward to do in detail is:

- Have Linux contain all important information
- Run a virtual machine (with Windows) with almost all the resources of the computer for applications that don't run on Linux
- Be able to have a moderately smooth operation with said Virtual machine (within obvious machine related restraints)

I do not need any specialized programming on Linux but am 100% willing to learn as long as it benefits the privacy of my data.

Looking forward to hear from everyone, thanks!

Comment: An alternative to your security concerns would be to have two accounts in MS-Windows, but never install drivers, or run software as admin from 3rd partys. I hear that MS-Windows is reasonably secure these days, as long as you are not hiding from the government, running for government office, … (or doing anything else that the NSA may be interested in (Hi Jeff how are the kids)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While VMs are great for high-performance compute applications, the one area that they have a lot of overhead in is graphics. If you've ever tried to use a VM, no matter if it's a Linux or Windows host with a Linux or Windows guest, with KVM, Hyper-V, VirtualBox, or VMWare, you've probably noticed that it's very low frame rate, has little hardware graphics acceleration, and is overall not friendly to use for graphical purposes, and probably completely unsuitable for gaming. Typically, high-performance gaming VMs use an additional graphics card dedicated to the VM itself through projects like [Looking Glass](https://looking-glass.hostfission.com/), which is passed through.

This is going to be fairly (read: very) hard, so you should probably stick with dual-booting.

However, there is a solution: passing your GPU through entirely to Windows and disconnecting it from Linux. You'll need to enable PCI-E passthrough in your BIOS—typically called IOMMU. After that, [there's a project](https://gitlab.com/YuriAlek/vfio/-/wikis/Use#windows) that will set this up entirely, then pass through your GPU, keyboard, and mouse to Windows, and then disconnect them once you shut it down. Here's a general installation script for Debian-based distros (such as Ubuntu, which you should probably use as a beginner) as the guide is mostly written for Arch Linux:

- Run `sudo apt install qemu ovmf git libvirt` in your terminal
- Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `intel_iommu=on iommu=pt` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. For example, if it was empty before, it should now be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=on iommu=pt"`.
- Verify that IOMMU works. Run `sudo dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU` and make sure that you see some output.
- Flash a new VBios on your GPU that allows it to be passed through. This is fairly hard. Follow [these steps](https://gitlab.com/YuriAlek/vfio/-/wikis/vbios) or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IP-h9IKof0) up until 7:15.
- Download [VirtIO drivers for Windows](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/archive-virtio/): pick the most recently modified folder and then the file "virtio-win.iso" within it.
- Download Windows from its website.
- Follow the rest of [this tutorial](https://gitlab.com/YuriAlek/vfio/-/wikis/Use#windows) from step 3. In "edit the script" in step 4, replace `lightdm` everywhere you see it with `gdm`. Change `windows.sh` in step 6 to `windows-virsh.sh`.

Comment: That's sounds rather complicated to my knowledge. You mentioned dual boot, does that mean I can have Linux and Windows on the same drive and then switch between the two? Say I store critical information like banking information only on Linux and then I use Windows as normal but without the "critical information". Does that sound viable?

Comment: @Rui Yes, and there's also *many* more guides for that. Sometimes booting will break when Windows does an update, but it will give each OS full usage of the hardware. Technically, malware on the Windows partition *could* harm or access the files on Linux when they couldn't in a VM, but the benefits greatly outweigh the downsides.

Comment: That's more reassuring than nothing. For my needs do you think it'll suit me? If so would you mind linking to well based guides on how to create said dual boot?

Comment: I agree. However doing hardware pass-through (or duel boot), is tearing down the wall between host and guest. The OP is concerned with security. Unfortunately this is a choose two situation: MS-Windows and GNU/Linux at the same time, performance, security, choose two.

Comment: @Rui https://www.itzgeek.com/post/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-alongside-with-windows-10-in-dual-boot/, use step 7a when you get to it. Install Windows first, then get Ubuntu started. When booting your installation disk for both OSes, make sure that if you see multiple entries in your motherboard's boot menu that you select the option that starts with `UEFI`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor there's no problems with passing the GPU to a guest. [IOMMU is secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150386/does-iommu-prevent-dma-attacks), and is used all the time in datacenters where security is key.

Comment: @lights0123 the answer by giles in that question states that in theory IOMMU may provide the protection (I did not know this), however it may differ in practice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install VirtualBox or VMWare Player (I recommend the former since VMWare Player often has troubles with new kernels)
2. Create a VM preferably with a fixed size disk (to avoid VM disk fragmentation). Allocate maybe 4-6GB of RAM for the VM and maybe 2-3 CPU cores.
3. Download a 64bit Windows installation ISO.
4. Insert the ISO into your VM and power it on.
5. After installing Windows, install VirtualBox additions. You can eject the DVD now.

You're basically done.

Some notes:

- Enabling EFI support in VirtualBox is not really necessary but can be done. I've found zero difference between running UFI and non-EFI versions.
- You can install a 32bit Windows version instead, and in this case you don't need to allocate more than 3GB of RAM for it but then your Windows applications won't be able to allocate more than 2GB of RAM.

Comment: Hi, this solution seems rather simple to what I expected and that's cool. In regards to the Linux distribution I should use do you have any recommendations and/or guides for that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I personally prefer Fedora but at times it can be unstable. If you want to install Linux and forget about it for many years, https://xubuntu.org/download/ Xubuntu **LTS** is the best choice. Ubuntu by default runs Gnome which I personally dislike for too many reasons.

Comment: Which beginner friendly one would you recommend the most to me? I've heard Ubuntu is the most popular one, not sure if this is true or not. Also on the matter of virtualization does do the VB and VMWare handle drivers by themselves or are there any issues I should take not beforehand?

Comment: Linux by itself is not very user-friendly, and again Ubuntu LTS could be the best choice for you. Both handle kernel drivers by themselves but again with VBox you'll run into fewer troubles. And in my experience it's faster. The last version of VMWare which I recommended was 5.5 but that was ages ago and now it cannot be even used with modern distros and it doesn't support new Windows versions.

Comment: I would go with Debian: I know it works well, and it does not try to take away your freedom. Ubuntu and MS-Windows do.

Comment: OMG, let's have a war on what Linux means (absolutely most Linux users think of Linux as Linux distros) and which distros are friendly or not (Debian is a whole lot less easy and Ubuntu has a much larger community, not to mention it has PPAs) . Freedom and crap while the OP is simply asking for a friendly distro without any strings attached.

Again, OP, start with Xubuntu LTS.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to do following

1. Install VirtualBox

https://techamor.com/installing-virtualbox-in-ubuntu/

2. Download Windows ISO from Windows Website.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10

3. Create a VM on Virtual Box and install Windows

https://www.extremetech.com/computing/198427-how-to-install-windows-10-in-a-virtual-machine

4. Use Windows and Linux Simultaneously

You need to tell us what is a specific issue if any to help you further.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi. In regards to the Linux distribution I should use, do you have any recommendations and/or guides for that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have not used much before, I would suggest you go for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply back! Assuming I install Ubuntu and do the Virtual Machine trick, are there any issues on running games and/or driver related issues that might happen or is it handled by the VM like a normal Windows installation?

Comment: Running Games totally depend on hardware requirements.. The Windows 10 VM will be sharing resources with Ubuntu.  I cant comment which games can give issues. 

I have tried games like American Army and Call of duty a couple of years ago and it ran fine. Cant comment on the latest versions

Comment: Let's say I want to run something like Witcher 3. My specs are stated on my post, is it runnable from the VM? that's the question I was asking

Comment: That will be a bit too much . Games will perform best when they have native access to hardware.  Best Answer will be experience. Try and Find out , and let the community know.

Comment: Please dont forget to mark an Answer as a solution once you are satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is Virtual Box. However:

- Performance of games will be poor. Enabling 3D acceleration will help, but will blow a hole in the wall between the guest and host.
- Gnu/Linux has good game support now (not as many as MS-Windows, but lots). Gnu/Linux is the OS that many mistakenly call Linux: Linux is the kernel used on Gnu/Linux, android and other OSes), Gnu/Linux is a UNIX like OS (or a Unix).
- Using MS-Windows for everything will not progress you toward the day that you are free.
- Everything that you do in MS-Windows can be done in Gnu/Linux. Not always the same tools though. There are a few app types that are still lacking e.g. 3D CAD.

## MS-Windows and GNU/Linux at the same time, performance, security, choose two.

To keep security separation between the host and guest VMs do stuff, that is not performent. There are solutions to increase performance, in theory to make the guest on par with the host. However this is done by removing the barrier between the guest and host.

With duel boot, each OS can do what ever it wants. e.g. access and change the all data, modify the other OS, …

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! For reading what you've said it means that with a VM I have security and with dual boot I have performance but never the two together. Is that correct?

Comment: 1) User did not ask for freedom 2) *"Everything that you do in MS-Windows can be done in Gnu/Linux"* - that's a lie. 3) *"Gnu/Linux has good game support now "* it's never had good support unless support means Wine/DXVK or Steam/Proton which do not guarantee anything 4) The user has never mentioned gaming even once 5) *"MS-Windows and GNU/Linux at the same time, performance, security, choose two"* - again, a lie. I've been running Windows in a VM since the early 00s and never had any issues with performance or security.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have had to performance problems ether but then I don't play games (first sentence of question). I have also not had any security problems with MS-Windows, but then I don't have to admin it. Every thing that you can do it true, just not every app (I mentioned CAD as an example). But it can do everything (Maybe you have to write a program).

Comment: *Maybe you have to write a program* can you write a program like 3D Max? Yes, that's a CAD application but there are literally thousands of others which are not available in Linux in any shape or form.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Stop agreeing with me.